# Line/arrow using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am having problems with something I think may be easy to solve but I haven't been able to fix it. I am doing a diagram in Latex and I need to connect different rectangles with a circle. The problem is that I do not know how "to tell latex" that both the line and the end of the line should have the same colour. I end up with the figures as I want, but the problem is that the arrowhead is black, not as the line colour I define.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{lc_blue}{RGB}{5,110,130}
\definecolor{lc_grey}{RGB}{160,170,160}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw=lc_blue, -latex', line width=1mm]
\begin{figure}
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}
   [place/.style={circle,draw=lc_blue,fill=lc_grey,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=35mm,text width=1cm},
transition/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=lc_blue,fill=lc_grey,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=25mm,minimum height=1cm}]
     \node (inc)  at ( 0,-4) [transition] {};
     \node (dial) at ( 0,4)  [transition] {};
     \node (lic)  at ( 0,0)  [place] {};
     \node (conf) at ( 4,0)  [transition] {};
     \node (cred) at (-4,0)  [transition] {};

     \node [black] at (inc)  {\textbf{Inclusión}};
     \node [black] at (dial) {\textbf{Diálogo}};
     \node [black] at (conf) {\textbf{Confianza}};
     \node [black] at (cred) {\textbf{Credibilidad}};
     \node [black] at (lic)  {\textbf{Legitimidad social}}; 
     \path [line] (cred.east) --  (lic.west);
     \path [line] (dial.south) -- (lic.north);
     \path [line] (conf.west) --  (lic.east);
     \path [line] (inc.north) --  (lic.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried your code and the arrows are bluish, as the lines, not black...

Comment: I took the liberty to complete the code snippet to a full document. When I run the example with TikZ 3.0, then I get colored arrow heads with the same color as the line.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are running pgfversion 2.10 right now.

You have 3 options to fix it:

1. Change the `draw=lc_blue` to `color=lc_blue`.

   ```
   \tikzstyle{line} = [color=lc_blue,-latex', line width=1mm]
   ```
2. Change the `draw=lc_blue` to `draw=lc_blue, fill=lc_blue`.

   ```
   \tikzstyle{line} = [draw=lc_blue, fill=lc_blue,-latex', line width=1mm]
   ```
3. Upgrade your  TikZ to 3.0.1

One example with option 3.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{lc_blue}{RGB}{255,110,130}
\definecolor{lc_grey}{RGB}{160,255,160}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw=lc_blue, -latex', line width=1mm]

\begin{tikzpicture}
   [place/.style={circle,draw=lc_blue,fill=lc_grey,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=35mm,text width=1cm},
transition/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=lc_blue,fill=lc_grey,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=25mm,minimum height=1cm}]
     \node (inc)  at ( 0,-4) [transition] {};
     \node (dial) at ( 0,4)  [transition] {};
     \node (lic)  at ( 0,0)  [place] {};
     \node (conf) at ( 4,0)  [transition] {};
     \node (cred) at (-4,0)  [transition] {};

     \node [black] at (inc)  {\textbf{Inclusión}};
     \node [black] at (dial) {\textbf{Diálogo}};
     \node [black] at (conf) {\textbf{Confianza}};
     \node [black] at (cred) {\textbf{Credibilidad}};
     \node [black] at (lic)  {\textbf{Legitimidad social}}; 
     \path [line] (cred.east) --  (lic.west);
     \path [line] (dial.south) -- (lic.north);
     \path [line] (conf.west) --  (lic.east);
     \path [line] (inc.north) --  (lic.south);
     \node at (-4,4) {pgfversion:\pgfversion};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

For equal color of line and arrows you need to define:

```
\path[line width=1mm, -latex', draw=lc_blue,fill=lc_blue]
```

or shortly:

```
\path[line width=1mm, -latex', lc_blue]
```

I will take opportunity and rewrote code into more short form. For this I add package `positioning`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

    \begin{document}
\definecolor{lc_blue}{RGB}{5,110,130}
\definecolor{lc_grey}{RGB}{160,170,160}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 21mm and 13mm,
     place/.style = {circle, draw=lc_blue, fill=lc_grey, thick,
                     inner sep=2mm, text width=24mm, align=center},
transition/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=lc_blue, thick,
                     fill=lc_grey, inner sep=2mm,
                     minimum size=24mm, minimum height=1cm},
             font = \bfseries]
\node (inc)  [transition]               {Inclusión};
\node (lic)  [place,above=of inc]       {Legitimidad social};
\node (dial) [transition,above=of lic]  {Diálogo};
\node (conf) [transition,right=of lic]  {Confianza};
\node (cred) [transition,left =of lic]  {Credibilidad};
%
\path[line width=1mm, -latex', draw=lc_blue,fill=lc_blue] 
    (cred) edge (lic)   (dial) edge (lic)
    (conf) edge (lic)   (inc)  edge (lic);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

It gives slightly different image (I reduce size of circle and wrote text in it in two lines, but this you can easy change to your original design):

[image]